# What characteristics do functions have, where $f(x,y) = -f(y,x)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

Edited the question. One commenter said these functions are antisymmetric. Does that mean they're not symmetric? Symmetric to what exactly? What are some general characteristics.

Comment: This certainly doesn't hold for all functions $f$.

Comment: Perhaps it holds for the function the teacher was talking about.

Comment: It sounds like this question is completely out of context. You need to think about what the teacher was showing you just before saying that $f(x,y)=-f(y,x).$ They must have said _something_ about $f$ that would allow making this conclusion. If you can find anything in your notes, edit it into the question, even if the conclusion still doesn't make sense; it might help someone explain the reasoning.

Comment: I suspect your teacher was talking about a *specific* function.  There are some functions for which this is true but in general it is not true as you have probably discovered yourself.  Example.  It is not true for $f(x,y) = 3x +2xy + 7y\ne -3y-2xy -7x =-f(x,y)$ but it is true for $f(x,y) = x^2y - xy^2= -y^2x + yx^2 = -f(y,x)$

Comment: This particular kind of functions are called **antisymmetric**, but not all function of two variables is such.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only true for some functions.

EG

$$f(x,y)=x^2-y^2=-f(y,x)=-(y^2-x^2)=x^2-y^2 $$

Comment: Ok, thanks. Some functions only. It doesn't seem to apply for linear functions.

Comment: Also f(x,y)=x-y works and all the functions in the form f(x,y)=g(x)-g(y)

Comment: @gimusi An immediate generalization of your remark can be found in the recent answer  (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2556717)

Comment: @JeanMarie I will give a look. Thanks!