# Challenging problem about $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y)+f(y,z)+f(z,x) = 0$ for all real $x, y, z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x,y)+f(y,z)+f(z,x) = 0$ for all real numbers $x, y$, and $z$. Prove that there exists a function $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y) = g(x)−g(y)$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$.

Attempt: Can we just set $z = 0$ and solve for $f(x,y)$?

Comment: I appreciate vadim123's feedback , but I still don't understand my solution is wrong. Can someone provide more insight about this problem, so I can see it from a different angle?

Comment: x,y, and z are not constants to be solved.  This will be true for *all* possible values of x,y, and z.

Comment: So it is true that $f(x,y) = -f(0,x) - f(y,0)$ for all $x,y$ but how can you set $g(x) = -f(x,0)$ and $g(y) = f(y,0)$?  If $g(x) = -f(x,0)$ then $g(y) =-f(y,0) \ne f(0,y)$..... unless it does.....

Comment: if $g(y) = -f(y,0)$ then why does this entail that $g(y) = f(0,y)$. How do they relate?

Comment: This is the step  I can't understand  $g(y)=−f(y,0)≠f(0,y)$ ..

Comment: Follow vadim123's hints.  It's all there.  $f (x,x)+f (x,x)+f (x,x)=0$ so $f (x,x)=0$.  And $f (x,y)+f (y,y)+f (yx)=f (x,y)+0+f (y,x)=0$ so $f (x,y)=-f (y,x) $.  So if we define $g (k)=f (k,56.3247) =-f (56.3247,k)$ then we $f (x,y)=0-f (y,56.3247)-f (56.3247,x)=-g (y)+g (x) $.

Comment: $f (y,0) $ most certainly *does* equal $-f (0,y) $.  You can easily prove that $f (a,b)=-f (b,a) $ because $f (a,b)+f (b,b)+f (b,a)=0$ and $f (b,b,)=0$.

Comment: 1) let $x=y=z $.  Then $3f (x,x)=0$ so $f (a)=0$.  2) let $x=x,y=y,z=x $ then $f (x,y)+f (y,x)+f (x,x)=f (x,y)+f (y,x)=0$ so $f (x,y)=-f (y,x) $.  Let $g (x)=f (x,c) $ for some constant $c $.  Then $-g (y)=-f (y,c)=f (c,y) $.  So $f (x,y)+f (y,c)+f (c,x)=f (x,y)+f (y,c)-f (x,c)=f (x,y)+g (y)-g (x)=0$.  So $f (x,y)=g (x)-g (y) $.

Comment: Ok, so what I want to know is why do we have to take into account that $-f(y,0) \neq f(0,y)$. Why do we care about that?

Comment: You need to take into account that $-f(y,0)$ ***!!!!DOES!!!!*** equal $f(0,y)$

Comment: $f$ is an unusual function in that $f(x,y) + f(y,z) + f(z,x) = 0$.  This is in general not true for most functions.  But when it is true: $f(x,y) + f(y,z) + f(z,x) = 0 \iff f(x,x) =0$ for all $x$ and $f(x,y) = -f(y,x)$ for all $x,y$, which are two other unusual conditions that are true for *THIS* function $f$ but not for $f$ in general.

Comment: The reason we take that into account is that if we set $g(x) = f(0,x)$ then  is because then $-g(y) = f(y,0)$.  !!!!BECAUSE!!!!! $f(y,0)  $ !!!!!DOES!!!!! equal $-f(0,y) = g(y)$.  Therefore $g(x) - g(y) = f(0,x) - f(0,y) = f(y,0) + f(0,x) = 0 - f(y,x) = f(x,y)$.  And that *is* the result we wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will *not* be true in general but it will be true for *this* unusual function that has the *unusual* property that:

$f(x,y) + f(y,z) + f(z,x) = 0$.

This means that $f(x,y) = -f(z,x)- f(y,z) $.

This is true for all $z$ so if we could define $g(w) = -f(c,w)$ and $g(w) = f(w,z)$ for some constant $c$ we would be done. (As $g(x) - g(y) = -f(c,x) -f(y,c)= f(x,y)$.)

But that would require that there be some constant $c$ so that $-f(c,w) =f(w,c)$ for all $w$ and that is not true in general.

But, $f$ is *not* a usual function.  Maybe this *IS* true for $f$.

Can we prove that $f(w,z) = -f(z,w)$ for all $w,z$.?

Let $x = y = w$: Then $f(w,w) + f(w,z)+ f(z,w) = 0$ so $f(w,z) = -f(z,w) - f(w,w)$.

Shoot!  That was so close but $-f(z,w) - f(w,w) \ne -f(z,w)$ unless $f(w,w) = 0$ and that  is not true in general.

But, again, $f$ is *not* a general function.  Maybe $f(w,w)$ *does* equal $0$ for all $w$.

Let $x = y = z = w$:  Then $f(w,w) + f(w,w) + f(w,w) = 0$ so $f(w,w) = 0$.

That's it!  We are done.

.....

If we set $g(w) = f(w,c)$ for some constant $c$ we get:

$f(x,y) + f(y,c) + f(c,x) = 0$ so

$f(x,y) = -f(c,x) - f(y,c) = -f(c,x) - g(y)$.

Now $f(c,x)+ f(x,x) + f(x,c) = 0$ so

$f(c,x) = -f(x,c) - f(x,x) = -g(x) - f(x,x)$ so

$f(x,y) = -f(c,x) - g(y) = g(x) + f(x,x) - g(y)$.

Now $f(x,x) + f(x,x) + f(x,x) = 0$ so $f(x,x) = 0$ so

$f(x,y) = g(x) +f(x,x) - g(y) = g(x) - 0 - g(y) = g(x) - g(y)$.

We are done.

Or for a third time:

$f(x,y) = -f(y,c) - f(c,x) $

$=-g(y) - (0 - f(x,x) - f(x,c))$

$= -g(y) + g(x) + f(x,x) $

$=g(x)-g(y) + \frac 13(f(x,x) + f(x,x) + f(x,x))$

$=g(x) - g(y) + \frac 13(0)$

$= g(x)-g(y)$.

Answer (score 11):

Hints:

1. Prove that $f(x,x)=0$ for all $x$.
2. Prove that $f(x,y)=-f(y,x)$ for all $x,y$.
3. Set $g(x)=f(0,x)$, and then apply the initial attempt (since modified) to prove that $f(x,y)=g(x)-g(y)$.

Comment: Here is my erroneous thinking, so you can fix it . If $f(x,y) = x^2 +y$ , so $f(x,0) = x^2$ which implies that $f(x,0) = g(x)$ because f(x,0) just depends on x.

Comment: @Dan, this function you give doesn't satisfy the property.  Just try following the hints.

Comment: But the thing is I don't understand why I have to do what you are telling me to do, so I still can't go with your approach until I understand why mine is wrong.

Comment: Your approach is wrong, because you do not have a proof structure leading from the hypotheses to the conclusion, rather some calculations.

Comment: 3f(x,x) = 0 , so f(x,x) = 0 and for 2 we just set (x,y,z) = (x,y,x); however, I still don't understand why I am doing this.

Comment: What does "setting  (x,y,z) = (x,y,x)" mean?  Can you set (1,2,3) = (1,2,1) when $3 \ne 1$.  x,y,z are not constants that can be set, they are variables that can scan any and all of real number

Comment: If $f(x,y) = x^2 +y$ then $f(x,y) + f(y,z) + f(z,x) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + y+z+x \ne 0$ in general.  Example $f(1,2) + f(2,3) + f(3,1) = 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 1 + 2+3 = 20 \ne 0$ so that was a complete waste of time.

Comment: $3f(x,x) = 0$ for *all* x.  Then *all* x is ket.  So $f(x,x) = 0$ for all $x$.   So what does $f(x,y) + f(y,y) +f(y,x)$ equal?  For *all* x,y?